# Reading in TSV with unescaped character in Pandas

Tags: python, csv

I have a TSV file where each line is a word token and its POS tag, separated by tabs.

```
The    DET
boy    NOUN
said    VERB
"    PUNCT
Hi    INTJ
Mum    NOUN
"    PUNCT
```

This will be used as a basis for a POS-Tagger later on. My problem is that whenever Pandas encounters the quotes, it returns back this:

```
                                   word    tag
0                                   The    DET
1                                   boy   NOUN
2                                  said   VERB
3  \tPUNCT\r\nHi\tINTJ\r\nMum\tNOUN\r\n  PUNCT
```

I have tried to explicitly define the quotes as an escape character, but it didn't work. The other thing I can think of is to escape them in the TSV files directly, but since I have many of them, and they have been generated for me by an external source, this will be tedious and time consuming.

Has anyone encountered this before and have a solution?

Comment: How are you reading the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `pandas` to ignore quoting when reading a file, in this case `pandas` uses the same configuration options as the builtin `csv` module, so you have to pass it the `QUOTE_NONE` constant from the csv module:

```
import csv
import pandas

pandas.read_table(fn, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, names=('word', 'tag'))
```